# Export some tables from sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an old sql file & I need to export some tables from it.

This file is too heavy, so I cant upload it to modify it by phpMyAdmin on server.

Is there a application like phpMyAdmin to modify sql file on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install [phpMyAdmin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/4.2.5/) or [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) on your local machine. Break your table down into chunks your server can manage, and then upload/import it that way.

Comment: I have internet speed limit! which is better to download?

Comment: Then I'd go for phpMyAdmin (3.7MB for English), compared to 30+ MB for MySQL Workbench